# VS не хочет подключать обработчик для поля ввода на android

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio

Хочу подключить обработчик для поля ввода, чтобы оно вызывало TextChanged только при завершении ввода. Вот сам код подключения:

```
settings_interval_value.EditorAction += EA;
```

А вот код обработчика:

```
public void EA(TextView.EditorActionEventArgs a)
{
    a.Handled = (a.Event != null && (a.Event.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter)) || (a.ActionId == ImeAction.Done);
}
```

Однако, VS мне сообщает "`Нет перегруженного метода для "EA", который соответствует делегату "EventHandler<TextView.EditorActionEventArgs>`"

Я пробовал перейти к определению этого события, там написано `public event EventHandler<EditorActionEventArgs> EditorAction;`.

В чем тут дело? VS опять бунтует, или я просто что-то забыл?

Answer (score 0):

Добавил еще один аргумент `object sender`, ошибки нету. Вот код:

```
public void EA(object sender, TextView.EditorActionEventArgs a)
{
    a.Handled = (a.Event != null && (a.Event.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter)) || (a.ActionId == ImeAction.Done);
}
```